# Deleting multiple items with one button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Help pls with a function **onDeleteNote** that removes active note, it did not quite work out for me as I am a beginner. Deleting multiple items with one button **onDeleteNote** does not work correctly, every time you add a note a basket(delete button) can is added.

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Main from "./components/Main";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [activeNote, setActiveNote] = useState(false);

  const onAddNote = () => {
    const newNote = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title: "Untitled Note",
      body: "",
    };
    setNotes([newNote, ...notes]);
  };

  const onUpdateNote = (updatedNote) => {
    const updatedNotesArray = notes.map((note) => {
      if (note.id === activeNote) {
        return updatedNote;
      }
      return note;
    });
    setNotes(updatedNotesArray);
  };

  const onDeleteNote = (noteId) => {
    setNotes(notes.filter((note) => note.id !== noteId));
  };

  const getActiveNote = () => {
    return notes.find((note) => note.id === activeNote);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-border">
        <Sidebar
          notes={notes}
          onAddNote={onAddNote}
          activeNote={activeNote}
          setActiveNote={setActiveNote}
        />
        <Main
          notes={notes}
          onDeleteNote={onDeleteNote}
          activeNote={getActiveNote()}
          onUpdateNote={onUpdateNote}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Sidebar.js

```
const Sidebar = ({ notes, onAddNote, activeNote, setActiveNote }) => {
  return (
    <div className="app-sidebar">
      <div className="app-sidebar-header">
        <button>Title ⇅</button>
        <button>Date ⇅</button>
      </div>
      <div className="app-buttons">
        <button onClick={onAddNote} className="button-new-save">
          + New
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="app-sidebar-notes">
        {notes.map((note) => (
          <div key={note.id} className="app-sidebar-note">
            <div
              className={`sidebar-note-title ${
                note.id === activeNote && "active"
              }`}
              onClick={() => setActiveNote(note.id)}
            >
              <strong className="note-title">{note.title}</strong>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Main.js

```
import bin from "../images/bin.png";
import magnifier from "../images/magnifier.png";

const Main = ({ onDeleteNote, activeNote, onUpdateNote, notes }) => {
  const onEditField = (key, value) => {
    onUpdateNote({
      ...activeNote,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };

  if (!activeNote)
    return <div className="no-active-note">List of notes is empty</div>;

  return (
    <div className="app-main">
      <div className="search">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by title"
          className="search-input"
        />
        <img src={magnifier} alt="search" />
      </div>
      <div className="app-main-note-edit">
        <div className="main-title-block">
          <p>Title</p>
          {notes.map((note) => (
          <img src={bin} alt="Delete" height={50} width={41} onClick={() => onDeleteNote(note.id)}/>
          ))}
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          placeholder="Note title"
          value={activeNote.title}
          onChange={(e) => onEditField("title", e.target.value)}
          autoFocus
        />
        <p>Description</p>
        <textarea
          id="body"
          placeholder="Write your note here..."
          value={activeNote.body}
          onChange={(e) => onEditField("body", e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className="app-buttons">
          <button onClick={onEditField} className="button-new-save">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

How it looks in the browser:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Ztw.png)

The basket(delete button) must remain the one for any quantity notes.

Comment: Use snippets https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
{notes.map((note) => (
          <img src={bin} alt="Delete" height={50} width={41} onClick={() => onDeleteNote(note.id)}/>
```

to

```
<img src={bin} alt="Delete" height={50} width={41} onClick={() => onDeleteNote(activeNote.id)}/>
```